# Red border around HBow in StackPane Javafx

Tags: javafx, fxml, controlsfx, hbox

I have a little question about `StackPanes`. In my application I have a `StackPane` and in it there is a `TabPane` and a searching mask. I have painted it provisionally with Paint.

[image]

The black frame shows a `TabPane` and the yellow frame shows the other layer, which also contains a search field (`HBox`). The tabs of my `TabPane` hhave a TreeView in it. Now I would like that if the search did not find anything, the frame (whole orange field) gets a red border. Now if I put a red border around the `HBox`, then it is not the border of the orange `HBox` that is red but the layer border (so the red border is shown like the yellow line). Can anyone tell me how to get the red frame around my `HBox`?

Here is my code:

```
<StackPane fx:id="TabVBox">
        <TabPane fx:id="TabPane" tabDragPolicy="REORDER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <Tab text=" + " fx:id="myFirstTab" closable="false">

            </Tab>
        </TabPane>
        <HBox fx:id="searchBox" visible="false" alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" pickOnBounds="false" styleClass="searchFilterBox">
            <TextField fx:id="filter" promptText="Search..."></TextField>
            <Button fx:id="applyFilter" onAction="#applyFilter" styleClass="searchFilerCss">
                <graphic>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon glyphName="SEARCH" size="10.0" styleClass="searchGlyphCss"/>
                </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="removeFilter" onAction="#removeFilter" styleClass="removeFilterCss">
                <graphic>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon glyphName="TIMES" size="12.0" styleClass="remoeGlyphCss"/>
                </graphic>
            </Button>
        </HBox>
</StackPane>
```

EDIT: I thinkg I should put the `HBox` in another container so that, I can position the `HBox` right but Im not familiar with other container than `VBox`.

Comment: Using `StackPane.alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT"`, `maxWidth="-Infinity"`, and `maxHeight="-Infinity"` for your `HBox` may accomplish what you want.

Comment: Slaw is right. To elaborate a bit: `StackPane` resizes its children to the size closest to its own size; since there are no upper bounds on the size of your `HBox`, it's grown to the size of the `StackPane`. To avoid this you need to set the max size to the value of the `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE` constant which happens to be `-1/0=-Infinity`. If you want to place the `HBox` at a distance from the `StackPane` bounds, add a `<StackPane.margin>` element with the appropriate insets to the `<HBox>` element.